# Как определить media запросом девайс, у которого скролл не имеет статичной позиции

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, media-queries

Я хочу сделать `@media` запрос для устройства, у которого нету статичной позиции скролла по ширине. Я не знаю как это гуглится и как это вообще найти. Обычно у телефона может не быть статичного размера скролла. Но у больших планшетов и телевизоров тоже может не быть статичного размера скролла.

Это для меня статичный скролл страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это не статичный, он как бы `fixed` или `absolute`, он лежит на контенте, а не отодвигает его:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что означает статичная позиция скролла и статичный размер скролла?

Comment: @NoSkill типа `position: static`, когда контент отодвигает другой контент

Comment: это называется скролл-бар в элементе и скролл-бар поверх элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь сделать нечто подобное: [Media Query width and vertical scrollbars](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201301/media_query_width_and_vertical_scrollbars/). Но данный функционал не реализован ни в одном браузере.

Если вам требуется знать размер скролл-бара (рус: полоса прокрутки), то вам придется его вычислить с помощью JavaScript, исходя из внешних и внутренних размеров элемента, а затем задать соответствующие классы. Причем размер скролл-бара придется пересчитывать каждый раз когда изменяются размеры самого элемента, или изменяется масштаб страницы.